How to Conditionally Activate Constraints in CP Optimizer (Docplex.cp) for a Scheduling Problem in Python?
I am working on a scheduling problem where I have a set of tasks that have a start and end time (already fixed and cannot be changed), I have to determine the number of agents needed to cover the tasks and make a schedule for each of them, respecting a set of constraints.
For now, I'm trying to make only daily schedules considering that I have a large amount of activities to cover in a day (100-400). The tasks could last from 10 minutes to 6 hours. One agent is needed for each task.
model = CpoModel()

intervals = []
for i in range(nb_activities):
    start = time_to_minutes(df["Heure de départ"].iloc[i])
    end = time_to_minutes(df["Heure d'arrivée"].iloc[i])
    intervals.append(model.interval_var(start=start, end=end, name=f'interval_{i}'))

activity_agent = model.integer_var_list(nb_activities, 0, nb_agents - 1, name="activity_agent")
agents_used = model.binary_var_list(nb_agents, name="agents_used")

for i in range(nb_agents):
    agent_has_activities = model.sum((activity_agent[j] == i) for j in range(nb_activities))
    model.add(agents_used[i] == (agent_has_activities > 0))
.
.
.


model.minimize(model.sum(agents_used))

solution = model.solve()

for i in range(nb_agents):
    for j in range(nb_activities):
        for k in range(j + 1, nb_activities):
            # If activity j and activity k are assigned to the same agent i, they must not overlap
            model.if_then( (activity_agent[j] == i) & (activity_agent[k] == i), model.end_before_start(intervals[j], intervals[k]) | model.end_before_start(intervals[k], intervals[j]))

I want to make sure that each couple of tasks that are assigned to one agent don't overlap. I tried to express it by saying that I want to ensure that tasks assigned to the same agent do not overlap. However, my attempts to express this constraint have not been successful.
I have researched the documentation of Docplex.cp, and looked for similar examples, but I haven't found a clear way to conditionally activate constraints.
How can I correctly implement the condition to ensure that tasks assigned to the same agent do not overlap in Docplex.cp? Is there a more efficient way to achieve this using the CP Optimizer?

If you are trying to allocate resources to a set of activities that are fixed in time, it's a resource allocation problem, not really a scheduling problem. You know the activity timings so you could just pre-process the sets of activites that overlap with each activity, and derive constraints from that. Or use the scheduling tools in CPO which have explicit modelling tools for interval activities and various things like cumulative functions over time to get a more direct modelling of your resource allocation problem.
